# Connecting Deployment method (github) through api/code

Tags: javascript, github, heroku, deployment

I was wondering if anyone had any remote idea on how to automatically connect a deployment method through github but through code. I can spin up a server, with env variables, and get a build running, which is great, but I need that last crucial step of having the deployment method connected to specific repo and a branch of it without needing to manually do so.

To summarize, I have the apps already deployed with an initial one time build, and env variables setup, **but then I have to manually connect the deployment method to a repo on Github and enable automatic deploys. How can I automate this part? **

[image: Deploy Method on heroku for Github]

You can see what portion of the server I'm referring to in the picture below, and then also I'll post my current code on how I spin up the server in javascript. Any help will be appreciated.

```
// Define an async function to deploy the app
export async function deployApp(name, envVariables, githubBranch) {
  try {
    // Create a new Heroku app
    const app = await heroku.post('/apps', {
      body: {
        name: name
      }
    });

    // Set config variables for the app
    for (const key in envVariables) {
      await heroku.patch(`/apps/${app.id}/config-vars`, {
        body: {
          [key]: envVariables[key]
        }
      });
    }

    // Deploy the code to the Heroku app
    // Note: This assumes that the code is hosted on a Git repository
    let tarballUrl = await fetchTar(githubBranch)
    let addGithub = await heroku.post(`/apps/${app.id}/builds`, {
      body: {
        source_blob: {
          url: tarballUrl
        }
      }
    });
    console.log("Add Github Results", addGithub)
  }catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```